# System.Array does not contain a definition for ToArray

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get this `int[]` array after the `.Split()`?

```
string s = "1,2,3,4";
int[] a = s.Split(',').ToArray<int>();
```

Comment: Can't convert from `string[]` to `int[]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Split doesn't give you magically int values, it returns an array of string. So you'll have to convert.

```
s.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing with `.ToArray<int>()`

Comment: Wouldn't `.Select(Convert.ToInt32)` work just as well?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum not in this case, I think (probably cause they are multiple overloads of Convert.ToInt32 ?).

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus oh right, inference would fail. Doing `.Select(int.Parse)` should work just fine and be shorter though.

Comment: @ZeeTee well no, this isn't doing any conversion, it's just an extension method, and the generic type must be the same.

Comment: the <int> part of the .ToArray<int> tells the compiler it should use the int version of the generic .ToArray method, as said before in the comments this will not do any conversion for you.

However, what it does is to allow you to force the compiler into using a specific version of generic code rather then have the compiler "guess" which one is the correct version

Answer (score 6):

I would do as Raphaël says, but if you are unfamiliar with lambda expressions (the x => .. part) you can use this instead. Both will give you an array of int's, Raphaëls example is to be preferable, but Lambda expressions can be scary when you don't know how they work :P (Basically it means "for each string x, do Convert.ToInt32(x)".

```
int[] a = s.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus sure it will compile, why wouldn't it? It's just a method group. No need to wrap things in a function wrapper.

Comment: @L.B yup, got to refresh my method group definition ;)